# В curl_execute возвращается [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8

Tags: php, curl

Я с одного домена пытаюсь связаться с другим доменам и получить данные в json формате с помощью cURL.

часть кода домена, с которого происходит обращение:

```
$URL='http://mysite.ru/rest/get-client-images-sizes';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$headers = array(
   // 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept:application/json',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

if($result === FALSE) echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
//Закрытие сеанса cURL
else echo "ok";

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

[image: Результат]

Плюс html - код страницы

Код второго домена с routing http://mysite.ru/rest/get-client-images-sizes

```
public function getClientImagesSizes(){

        $img_url_array = [
            0 => 'infodata---005-008-19-2-1---algus1---1-DSCN2675.jpg',
            1 => 'infodata---005-008-19-2-1---algus1---DSCN2679.jpg',
            2 => 'infodata---005-008-19-2-1---algus1---DSCN2682.jpg',
            3 => 'infodata---005-008-19-2-1---algus1---DSCN2690.jpg',
        ];

$json = json_encode($img_url_array);

 return new JsonResponse([ 'data' => $json, 'method' => 'GET', 'status'=> 200]);
```

Подскажите, почему Возвращается html код, а не переменная $json?

Comment: _Плюс html - код страницы_ и что в этом html-коде? json в виде текста? Может он просто возвращает html с описанием ошибки?

Comment: html-кода страницы авторизации. Роутинг, к которому происходит обращение через curl, закрыт для пользователей, кроме администратора.

Comment: ну тогда надо сначала авторизоваться. выяснить как авторизуются на целевом сайте, сначала сделать запрос с логином и паролем, получить куку или токен, потом уже с ними запрашивать json. Но полюбому ваш вопрос не по теме. Нет ошибки курла или пхп, просто ограничен доступ

Comment: Спасибо. А в функции, из которой curl_exec получает данные, надо оставить строку  return new JsonResponse([ 'data' => $json, 'method' => 'GET', 'status'=> 200]);  ?
И добавлять ли заголовок Content-type:application/json ?

Comment: `JsonResponse` и есть обертка над `Response`, которая сама ставит `Content-type:application/json`. (если у вас симфони, из контекста не понятно, что за фреймворк)

Comment: Просто до указанного контроллера запрос не доходит, поскольку его перекидывает в контроллер авторизации, который возвращает html форму

Comment: Да, симфони. Делаю на Друпал все